# Using ICS to redirect users?

Tags: c#, networking, netsh

I made a network using netsh and ICS. But i want to be able to redirect each request to my website.

Like This:

Computer A requests the website www.Google.com.

Host responds with my_website.

Is this possible in any way?

Answers are much appreciated.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: if you would notice the tags, that would be awesome Marc B

Comment: @CSharpUser267 How is this related to C#...I don't follow? Are you asking how to sniff packets and change them? Perhaps have a look at pcap-sharp if that's what you're after.

Comment: @CSharpUser267 If this is not the case, please advise how it relates to C#

Comment: @john its nearly the case. I want to respond with my own website. i dont want to change them, i want to send packets containing my own website from the start.

Comment: @john and if i could do all this is in c#...

Comment: @CSharpUser267 I've posted an answer for you. You will need to do some research into how to use sharp-pcap (I'm not that familiar with it I'm afraid). You will need to change the response packets / inject your own response packet with a redirect. If you're not familiar with the HTTP protocol you will also need to look into this. I hope my answer helps anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sharp-pcap wrapper (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/) to detect web requests and inject a 307 status HTTP response informing the originator of the request that the website they requested has moved to the location of your website.

The way this works:

1) I open my browser and navigate to http://www.google.com

2) My browser sends a request to the server of the website requesting / (i.e. index)

3) On the ICS pc my request is picked up and a response, redirecting me to http://www.yourwebsite.com is sent instead.

4) My browser receives the response and then tries to load http://www.yourwebsite.com instead

5) When your code picks up requests to http://www.yourwebsite.com, it allows the packets to flow normally